# How set accessory type when tabel view is enbled to editing?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, indicator

I am using the UITableView properties to edit it. 
theTableView.editing = YES;
theTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

It is working fine, the row is selected and I am getting into the next controller but I need to display the the accessoryType in the row. I am using below line for that but even though it is not working.
Is there any property or any thing missing to display the indiactor.

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

I am using the below code for table view.

```
theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableRect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; 
theTableView.editing = YES;
theTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
theTableView.delegate = self;
theTableView.dataSource = self;
theTableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
theTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
theTableView.autoresizingMask=YES;
theTableView.allowsSelection=YES;
theTableView.sectionHeaderHeight=5;
theTableView.sectionFooterHeight=5;

[myView addSubview:theTableView];
```

Please help me.

THank You,
Madan Mohan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the editingAccessoryType property of the UITableViewCell class.